# convert http obervable response to array supported by ngFor

Tags: typescript, observable, angular5

I'm trying to load select option dynamically based on API response and for http request, I'm using obervables in Angular5.

But it parsing response into select option throws below error.

```
Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays




ngOnInit() {  

    this.roles = this.roleService.getRoles();
    console.log("Roles Are here",this.roles);
}
}
```

`html`

```
 <select id="userrole" class="form-control " name="userrole" formControlName="userrole" data-live-search="true">
          <option *ngFor="let p of roles" value={{p[0]}}>{{p[1]}}</option>
        </select>
```

Check Plunkr here [Code](https://plnkr.co/edit/77nVko57Aj6UgBX4htfm?p=preview)

Comment: What is the value of the 'this.roles'?

Comment: @Niral Check Plunkr, I've added API call there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below will work:

```
this.roleService.getRoles().subscribe(roles => {
  this.roles = roles;
});
```

You can access the response data in the `subscribe`.

Updated HTML:

```
<div>
  <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
</div>
<div class="container row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <form [formGroup]="userRegform" novalidate>
      <fieldset class="form-group">
        <select id="userrole" class="form-control " name="userrole" formControlName="userrole" data-live-search="true">
          <option *ngFor="let p of roles" [value]="p['ROLE_ID']">{{p['ROLE']}}</option>
        </select>
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset class="form-group">
        <select class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true">
          <option data-tokens="ketchup mustard">Hot Dog, Fries and a Soda</option>
          <option data-tokens="mustard">Burger, Shake and a Smile</option>
          <option data-tokens="frosting">Sugar, Spice and all things nice</option>
        </select>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```